Pooled Hazard Ratio or Crude events (M-H to RR or OR) for mortality outcomes in Meta-Analysis?
I'm performing a MA to estimate the effect of treatment A respect to Placebo (or propensity-matched control group) respect to all-cause death.
All the studies included in my MA report both crude events and also HR with 95 % CI (usually Cox Regression Model). Thus, i can perfrom either a pooled effects with M-H model with Crude Events or a contrast level with inverce variance (LogHR).
My question is: which is the best approach and how should i differently interpret the pooled results (LogHR or RR/OR with H-M).

@Björn
Thansk for your exhaustive answer. Following what you said, using an HR as a polled effect for a meta-analysis aiming to investigate mortality, with results that can be applied to populations outside the analyzed studies, seems to me the most scientifically correct strategy (also because one of the most representative studies in terms of numerosity does not report raw events but an HR > therefore using an HR as a RR to be included in the calculation as some suggest seems to me a somewhat incorrect approximation).
Furthermore, using HR as a pooled effect size, the heterogeneity I find is less than that obtained by inserting raw events (probably because some studies included have found fewer events than expected).
However, I would like to ask you four further questions:

The included studies report HR and upper/lower limits with 95% CI but do not report the standard error > E.g., all-cause death HR 0.96 (95% CI, 0.78 - 1.19) p 0.21. To compute a pooled effect with inverse variance on RevMan I use the calculator to insert the HR, the CI and lower and upper limit > is therefore the calculator that derives LogHR and Standard Error. Is it still a statistically acceptable procedure or is it an approximation?
Should a meta-analysis of this type, i.e., using HR as a pooled effect, be more appropriately called time to event meta-analysis?
Some studies included in the meta-analysis are not RCTs but observational studies with propensity-matched analyses. In this case, two HR values (adjusted and unadjusted) are usually reported. In the case of these specific studies, is it more correct to use HRs adjusted to obtain a pooled effect that is more correctly applicable to an external population, or is the opposite true?
Is a pooled HR enough to calculate a NNT? Nowing a rate incidence for each of the included studie is possible to compute a pooled rate incidence in the tho arms to calculate a NNT? Here an example: The reported hazard ratio was h=0.72 with 95% confidence interval 0.55 to 0.92. The number needed to treat at 2 years is thus estimated as 1/(0.330.72–0.33)=8.32.

Thanks for your attention.

Hi Kjetil. I'm new on this platform. How can I expand with my further questions to Born? Thanks

A time-to-event model such as Cox regression accounts for differences in follow-up. E.g. if one arm has more people not being followed to the end because of unpleasant side effects, you avoid counting this as a positive in the way a proportion (RR or OR) would treat it. It arguably gives you a more transportable treatment effect (more likely to be applicable to a new population/different follow-up duration), while a OR or RR cannot mathematically stay the same across different populations (with all possible different base risks) and trial durations (although it could be the case that the differences are small enough that maybe you can argue it doesn't matter too much).
However, a hazard ratio is not a collapsible effect measure (nor is an odds ratios), so that the estimates of the benefit for a patient will be smaller than they really are if you omit important covariates from the model (in the case of crude proportions for an odds ratio, you essentially assume there's no important covariates). In contrast the risk ratio (or the difference in proportion) is collapsible. If you are only interested in the population average effect for the population studied in these particular studies, there's less of a problem, although the causal inference community does like its collapsible effect measures.
How much each of the these considerations matters in your case is hard to guess. E.g. a risk ratio might be strictly speaking wrong to use, but give pretty sensible results that are approximately okay.
Another consideration is that people usually struggle to interpret hazard ratios (and odds ratios) correctly, but can to some extent interpret risk ratios about right (some people would also argue for differences in proportions and/or number needed to treat).
EDIT
Regarding the added questions:

Back-calculating standard errors for a log-hazard ratio from confidence intervals and/or p-values and/or the number of patients with an event is commonly done. To some degree it will be an approximation (and more so from number of events etc.), but not terribly concerning (even assuming a normal distribution for estimate +- SE for things like hazard ratios, risk ratios, odds ratio is only an approximation, but that's widely done).
Meta-analyzing time-to-event data is definitely a meta-analysis, that's a very general term. Sure, to be more specific, one could say things like "aggregate data time-to-event meta-analysis", just like you might say "aggregate data binomial outcome meta-analysis" or "individual patient-data continuous outcome meta-analysis".
Unadjusted analyses of observational studies are rarely of any value for assessing treatment effects. The question is whether the adjustments are adequate to make you trust the evidence from the studies sufficiently to include them (there's of course all sorts of in-between options like including/excluding them in a sensitivity analysis, down-weighting them - possibly dynamically depending on how much they match randomized evidence etc.). Of course, there's all sorts of extra problems with non-randomized studies (like covariate measurement error possibly no longer being ignorable, omission of important predictors - including those omitted due to non-availability - from propensity scores...).
No, you cannot directly calculate anything like a NNT (or number of patients you need to treat for X units of time) from a relative effect measure (whether it's HR, OR or RR). You can get that only from a difference in exponential rates, difference in proportion with an event at time X etc., which you can obtain either after fitting a model that is already parameterized in terms of this parameter or even after fitting e.g. a an or exponential proportional hazards model via a method like that of Steingrimsson et al. (2017) (that one is for when you work with proportions, but the same idea transfers to e.g. exponential hazard rates). The latter approach seems to be the preferred option of the  the literature. However, it is not that obvious how that combines with meta-analysis (I guess one could meta-analyze differences in hazard rates, not sure how else one would do this) and differences (in hazard rates, proportions etc., as well as relatedly NNTs) notoriously are very, very badly transportable treatment effect measures (because absolute differences are usually larger for the same relative effect just because the study population has a higher risk).


Thank you very much @Björn. Below is a comment and some questions I would like to ask you to conclude this speech. I hope you can answer me.

Thanks a lot @Björn
